# Erro ao adicionar valor no array, valores repetidos

Tags: java, array, java-processing

Eu tenho dois arrays, A e B.

Eu criei 3 funções nas quais eu pego um valor do início do array A  e do array B, removo os valores, comparo os valores e se o valor de A é maior que de B, eu adiciono os 2 valores no final do array A, ou caso contrário, adiciono na lista B. O problema é que uma das funções está dando erro e eu não consigo achar o erro. Quando dou um print no array, os arrays que tinham valores únicos, passam a ter valores repetidos.Alguém pode me ajuda a encontrar e solucionar o erro?

Essa função pega um carta do início do array. SE encontra -1, é por o index está vazio, e então deveria pegar a próxima carta disponível.

```
  int getValorInicio (int[] arrCards, int topPonteiro) { 
    int card=0;

    if (arrCards[topPonteiro]!=-1) {
       card=arrCards[topPonteiro];
    }else{
       for(int i=0; i<arrCards.length; i++){
          if (arrCards[i]!=-1){
             card=arrCards[i];
             break;
          }
       }
     }
     return card;
}
```

Essa função remove a carta, e indica o próximo indice vazio.:

```
int removeCard(int[] arrCards, int topPonteiro) { 
  if(arrCards[topPonteiro] != -1){
    arrCards[topPonteiro]=-1; 
    topPonteiro=(topPonteiro+1)%arrCards.length;    
  } 
  return topPonteiro;
}
```

E finalmente essa função adiciona e retorna a próxima posição livre, mas parece que ela adiciona várias vezes o mesmo valor, quando não deveria isso.

```
    int addFinalArr(int [] arrCards, int ultimoPonteiro, int card) {
       int nextPosition=0;
       if (arrCards[ultimoPonteiro]==-1 && ultimoPonteiro!=ultimoPonteiro+1) {
         arrCards[ultimoPonteiro]=card; 
       }
       else{
          for(int i=0; i<arrCards.length; i++){   
             if (arrCards[i]==-1 && arrCards[i]!=arrCards[0]){
                nextPosition=i;
                break;
             }
             nextPosition=i;
          }
      }   
   return nextPosition;  
}
```

Comment: Tu removes os valores lidos dos arrays, antes de fazer tuas comparações?

Comment: Sim. Eu pego os valores, comparo e depois adiciono na lista que teve a carta de maior valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entendi seu problema mas olhando seu código as coisas ficaram meio confusas, o que você precisa e entender os conceitos de fila, pilha e lista de estrutura de dados e implementá-los (dê uma estudada e muito útil).

Retirar do primeiro e inserir no ultimo elemento é do conceito de **FILA**(Primeiro a Entrar Ultimo a Sair), no entanto sua FILA é personalizada porque ela retira um elemento do primeiro de cada array e insere no ultimo de do array1 ou array2 conforme sua regra.

Em Java você terá que fazer os métodos retornando os arrays novos já que essa linguagem não trabalha com ponteiros (você não consegue acessar um array a partir de dentro de um método invocado), resumindo ficaria desta forma.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    //o zero(0) representa casas vazias repare que o 
    //cartasA tem o primeiro elemento maior (5).
    int[] cartasA = {5,3,4,5,10,2,2,5,6,5,5,4,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int[] cartasB = {3,3,4,5,10,2,2,5,6,5,5,4,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    //imprime array cartasA antes de processar
    for (int i : cartasA) {
        System.out.print(i+",");
    }

    //armazena os dois primeiros elementos para adicionar mais tarde
    int tmpA = cartasA[0];
    int tmpB = cartasB[0];

    //remove o primeiro elemento
    cartasA = removerPrimeiro(cartasA);
    cartasB = removerPrimeiro(cartasB);

    //identifica qual array deve inserir os elementos no fim
    if(tmpA > tmpB){
        cartasA = inserirFim(cartasA, tmpA, tmpB);
    }else{
        cartasB = inserirFim(cartasB, tmpB, tmpA);
    }

    //imprime array cartasA depois de processar        
    System.out.println("");
    for (int i : cartasA) {
        System.out.print(i+",");
    }

}

static int[] removerPrimeiro(int[] cartas){
    //se o array estiver vazio retorna ele mesmo
    if(cartas[0] == 0)
       return cartas;

    //percorre o array deslocando os elementos para esquerda
    for (int i = 0; i < cartas.length - 1; i++) {
        cartas[i] = cartas[i+1];
    }
    //remove o ultimo elemento que o for não pode alcançar
    cartas[cartas.length - 1] = 0;
    return cartas;//retorna o novo array sem o primeiro valor
}

static int[] inserirFim(int[] cartas, int a, int b){
    //percorre o array em busca do ultimo elemento
    for (int i = 0; i < cartas.length - 1; i++) {
        if(cartas[i] == 0){
            //insere os dois valores nas duas ultimas posições
            cartas[i] = a;
            cartas[i + 1] = b;
            break;
        }
    }
    return cartas;//retorna o novo array
}
```

Saída do array cartasA:

antes de executar

[**5**,3,4,5,10,2,2,5,6,5,5,4,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
(repare o 5)

depois de executar

[3,4,5,10,2,2,5,6,5,5,4,6,**5**,**3**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
(repare que o 5 saiu e entrou o 5 no final junto com o 3 do array cartasB)

Espero que tenha ajudado.

**UPDATE**

Tente este remover

```
/**
 * neste caso os arrays cartasA e cartasB devem estar declarados static
 * para o metodo conseguir acessar nele, e fazer os metodos separados
 * um para cada baralho
 * @param cartas
 * @return 
 */
static int removeCartasA(){
    int resp = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < cartasA.length; i++) {
        //procura valor -1
        if(cartasA[i] != -1){
            resp = cartasA[i];//armazena valor para retornar
            cartasA[i] = -1;//remove substituindo com -1
            break;//sai do loop
        }
    }
    return resp;//retorna o valor removido
}

static int removeCartasB(){
    int resp = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < cartasB.length; i++) {
        //procura valor -1
        if(cartasB[i] != -1){
            resp = cartasB[i];//armazena valor para retornar
            cartasB[i] = -1;//remove substituindo com -1
            break;//sai do loop
        }
    }
    return resp;//retorna o valor removido
}
```

Comment: Você diminou o tamanho do array, e eu não fazer isso. Eu colocar -1 onde nao tem carta. Depois no final eu comparo.

Comment: A largura do array e constante (que deve ser do tamanho total do seu baralho ok?), onde não tem carta eu coloquei zero(0) você pode substituir por -1, para que seu baralho funcione corretamente ao remover uma carta do topo, você deve deslocar os valores da direita para esquerda ( valor da posição [1] vai para [0], valor da posição [2] vai para [1], ...) assim você remove a primeira carta, e para adicionar carta no final você deve localizar onde esta vazio e adicionar as duas cartas, esse é o conceito de trabalhar com FILA.

Comment: Veja na saída do exemplo que fiz para você. o elemento [0] =5 (Topo) saiu e os elementos 5(primeiro do baralhoA) e 3(primeiro do baralhoB) entraram no final do baralhoA. onde tem Zeros(0) considere vazio no seu caso você pode substituir por -1 sem problemas e só trocar no código onde for 0 por -1.

Comment: Seu array (baralho) deve manter os elementos sempre agrupados na esquerda, e os vazios sempre a direita, desta forma sua aplicação funcionará corretamente.

Comment: A função remove, só remove se a carta é não é -1. Ela remove a carta e retorna a próxima posição que não é -1.

Comment: fiz um update veja se atende agora

Comment: Usei um print para pegar os valores e a função remove pega -1 se cartasA possuem valores e cartasB possuem -1. Como eu faço para quando chegar no final do array retornar e verificar se existem mais valores para serem removidas?

Comment: Valeu @Luciano, consegui arrumar o meu código. Tuas dicas me ajudaram muito.